# .getText() returning NullPointerException in real device automation test

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium

Any time I am using `driver.findElement(By.anything("")).getText();` I get `NullPointerException`. On android real device testing.

- Appium 1.8.1
- Samsung S8
- ChromeDriver 2.38
- ChromeBrowser Latest

Bellow code from my test base to initialize driver, might be problem there? Them missing part of the code is for initializing `Driver`.

```
    if (driver == null) {
        switch (prop.getProperty("browser")) {
        case "chrome":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", prop.getProperty("chrome.driver.path"));
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong driver was chosen! Plsease choose the driver.");
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    return driver;
}
public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> initializeMobileDriver() {
    if (Mdriver == null) {
    switch (prop.getProperty("MobileBrowser")) {
        case "android":
            capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.CHROME);
            capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true"); 
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.SUPPORTS_FINDING_BY_CSS, true);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, prop.getProperty("DeviceName"));
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, prop.getProperty("AppiumVersion"));
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.ANDROID);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, prop.getProperty("PlatformName"));
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, prop.getProperty("PlatformVersion"));
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, prop.getProperty("DeviceName"));
            capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", "true");
            try {
                Mdriver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
                driver = Mdriver;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(" error is " + e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong driver was chosen! Plsease choose the driver.");
        }
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return Mdriver;
}
```

Any code simple code can be used and it returns null.

@Test
public static void SimpleGetTextTest() {

```
    driver.get("https://google.com")

    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Java"+Keys.ENTER);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'MUxGbd']")).getText();
```

This returns NullPointerException

Comment: I am not able to see any getText() in the code you shared ? Please add correct code

Comment: public static void SimpleMobileGetText() {
  driver.get("https://google.com");
  driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Java"+Keys.ENTER);
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'MUxGbd']")).getText();

Returns null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

Basically as you can see in the code I used  Mdriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);, where AndroidDriver = Mdriver;

I change it to RemoteDriver on both instances and everything started to work. Hope this helps